# Chrome storage returning undefined async/await

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous

I'm getting myself confused on async/await as I build a simple chrome extension that returns saved data from local storage.

I don't seem to understand why my function returns undefined, but the inner function returns an object.

I might be misunderstanding promises and async/await, but I can't seem to figure this out.

```js
// Loads saved data from local storage and sets the selected station to the saved selection
const loadSavedData = async () => {
  let key = "vin6"; // key to retrieve from local storage

  await chrome.storage.local.get([key], (result) => {
    if (!result[key]) return;
    console.log(result); // this gets printed out on the console 
    return result[key];
  });
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const data = loadSavedData();
  data.then((res) => {
    console.log(res); // this prints out as undefned
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `loadSavedData()` function doesn't return anything (thus `undefined`):

```js
const loadSavedData = async () => {
  ...
  await chrome.storage.local.get([key], (result) => {
    if (!result[key]) return;
    console.log(result); 
    return result[key]; // You are returning from the callback, not the main function!!!
  });
};
```

2. Using async/await is to *avoid* using promises. So why are you using `data.then()` in your event listener???

A solution to these problems would be the following, entirely dropping the async/await (not tested)

```js
// Loads saved data from local storage and sets the selected station to the saved selection
const loadSavedData = () => {
  let key = "vin6"; // key to retrieve from local storage

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    chrome.storage.local.get([key], (result) => {
      if (!result[key]) return;
      console.log(result);
      resolve(result[key]);
    });
  });
  
};


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const data = loadSavedData();
  data.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
});
```